# Attempting to lock a spinlock in the down function results in freezing

Tags: c, linux-kernel, semaphore

I am attempting to implement my own version of a semaphore into a linux vm and am running into a crash when I attempt to lock a spinlock inside the down function. Using GDB I found that the down is called immediately after the create function so the problem is definitely there.

Here is the create function:

```
asmlinkage long sys_create(int value, char name[32], char key[32]){
    
      struct sem *new_sem = (struct sem*) kmalloc(sizeof(struct sem), GFP_ATOMIC);
      struct sem_node *new_sem_node = (struct sem_node*) kmalloc(sizeof(struct sem_node), GFP_ATOMIC);
      struct sem_node *curr_sem = sem_list_head;
      new_sem_node->sem = new_sem;
      spin_lock(&sem_lock);
      new_sem->sem_id = IDcntr++;
      spin_lock_init(&(new_sem->lock));
      strncpy(new_sem->key, key, 32);
      strncpy(new_sem->name, name, 32);
      if(curr_sem == NULL)
      {
        sem_list_head = new_sem_node;
      }
      else
      {
        while(curr_sem->next != NULL)
        {
          curr_sem = curr_sem->next;
        }
        curr_sem->next = new_sem_node;
      }
      spin_unlock(&sem_lock);
      return new_sem->sem_id;
    }
```

Functions spin_lock, spin_unlock, and spin_lock_init are working as intended. The down function calls:

```
    spin_lock(&(sem_list_head->sem->lock));
```

right at the beginning and freezes. To be more specific, in the gdb terminal, I try and get to the next line and it stops and in the actual machine it's completely stopped. No other functions are called between the create and down function. Below is the header file that defines the sem_node, process_node, and sem objects used in the create and down functions:

```
int IDcntr = 1;
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(sem_lock);

struct sem_node
{
   struct sem* sem;
   struct sem_node* next;
};

struct process_node
{
   struct process_node* next;
   struct task_struct* task;
};

struct sem
{
   int value;
   long sem_id;
   spinlock_t lock;
   char key[32];
   char name[32];
   struct process_node* head;
   struct process_node* tail;
};

struct sem_node* sem_list_head = NULL;
```

Through independent testing the function DEFINE_SPINLOCK and object spinlock_t are working as intended. After thorough debugging the problem is in the create function. I freely admit that I am still learning how semaphores work so chances are I didn't set variables correctly or define things correctly. Any help in pointing me the right way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to be very careful in spinlock-protected section. E.g. inifinity loop or any crash under it could cause freezing the whole system. For debugging purposes you may remove (comment out) `spin_lock` and `spin_unlock` calls and try to catch unusual behavior. Meanwhile, you declare two **local variables** with the **same name** `new_sem`: the first one is of type `struct sem *` and the second one is of type `struct sem_node *`. This is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I had edited the code to remove my name from it since in my original code I put my name in one of them as a placeholder and never got around to changing it, so that definitely isn't the issue.

Comment: I attempted commenting out the spin locks and unlocks yet the program still freezes as soon as it hits the spin_lock in the down function. I know for a fact that it goes straight from the create to the down function with nothing in between, but when I tried locking that same lock in the create function it worked, but not in the down function. Does that help at all? @Tsyvarev

Comment: I don't see a place where you update list head `sem_list_head`. Probably, updating should be performed in function `sys_create`.

Comment: In `sys_create`, you should probably put `curr_sem = sema_list_head;` under protection of the `sem_lock` spin-lock too.